# How to add a custom Link into $content['links']?

Tags: 7, theming, nodes, navigation

I need help with solving following problem:

In my node content type (called "hotel") I'd like to add a custom link to the existing links which are put out via $content['links'].

The custom link shall only appear at the hotel content type.

What I have to do? What theme function do I have to modify and how?

thanks for any help.

phil

Comment: A quick search revealed this post.
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19877/how-to-programmatically-add-links-to-the-links-variable

Comment: Thanks a lot Rotem :) . This example works fine generally. But if I want to create a link with some $get parameters it don't work. 
For example:
I want to create a link like "link-to-my-node?param1=value1".
This is my PHP code:
<code>

function globewheeler_node_view_alter(&$build) {
       
    $build['links']['node']['#links']['add-hotel-image'] = array(
    'title' => t('Upload a hotel image'),
    'href' => 'node/add/hotelbild',
    'html' => TRUE,
    'attributes' => array(
      'title' => t('Upload a new hotel image!'),
      'query' => array('param1' => '10'),
     ),
   );
}
</code>