# load node author uid to be used as contextual link inside template.php D7

Tags: 7, theming, navigation

I need to load node author uid to be used as part of a href link inside template.php, I managed to add a **contextual link** according to this [post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19877/how-to-programmatically-add-links-to-the-links-variable/19883#19883), and call it from node.tpl.php but I can't access node author uid to complete my link. I have a view with the following path: `/userview/%/post`, link inside node.tpl.php it appears, but does not work. I tried to do it by custom module, but I do not know how to load the 'node being viewed' in a custom module, that's why I'm trying to do it in template.php. Any help will be appreciated.

This is my code in template.php

```
function MYTHEME_node_view_alter(&$build) { 

         $node_author = user_load($node->uid);

          // Add your own custom link
          $build['links']['node']['#links']['user-post'] = array(
            'title' => t('User post'), 
            'href' => '/userview/' . $node_author . '/post', 
            'html' => TRUE, 
            'attributes' => array(
              'title' => 'User post',
            ),
          );


        }
```

Comment: nid from url in template.php? I don´t know how to do that.

Comment: if you are getting node nid, then $node = node_load(nid); $node->uid gives uid

Comment: You can access **uid** as **$uid** in `node.tpl.php`. Please refer [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7). Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks, but I need to access it from template.php. my site is multilingual, so I have to translate text links. I can´t translate contextual links from node.tpl.php

Comment: I could not load $node, I'm sure there is a way to do it, all I get is "Notice: Undefined variable: node"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just a tiny mistake , use **$build['#node']->uid** instead **$node->uid**  :)

```
function MYTHEME_node_view_alter(&$build) { 

         $node_author = user_load($build['#node']->uid);

          // Add your own custom link
          $build['links']['node']['#links']['user-post'] = array(
            'title' => t('User post'), 
            'href' => '/userview/' . $node_author . '/post', 
            'html' => TRUE, 
            'attributes' => array(
              'title' => 'User post',
            ),
          );


        }
```

Comment: thanks zhilevan, but I have an error -- "Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in click_node_view_alter() (line 102 -". Line 102 is 'href' => '/userview/' . $node_author . '/post', how can I fix it?

Comment: @pinueve you're welcome because you should use uid instead user object
try this  (if you want user id)

`'href' => '/userview/' . $node_author->uid . '/post',`
or this if you want username
`'href' => '/userview/' . $node_author->name . '/post',`

Comment: zhilevan, that did the trick, I upvoted your answer, thanks a lot.